# Как правильно поставить запятую?

Tags: пунктуация

как всегда, пропускаю самое интересное

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: Как всегда, пропускаю самое интересное.

Как всегда - вводное слово со значением степени обычности: КАК ВСЕГДА, КАК ПРАВИЛО, КАК НИКОГДА, КАК ОБЫЧНО. Обычно находится в начале или середине предложения, например: . День начинался, как всегда, в тумане.

Но: Сегодня всё как всегда. Оборот входит в состав именного сказуемого и не обособляется.